# Detect what is running on an open port?

Tags: ports, nmap

I have a wireless camera in my network. Running nmap on the camera, I discovered that the port 1010 is open but I could not find what it is used for. I looked in the administration pannel and did not find any application that was configured to use that port. With nmap or wireshark, it is qualified as "surf".

I can connect to it using telnet, it works but I don't have a shell (so not a telnet server), I tried to send GET or HELO message but I had no reply. I tried using usual applications as ftp or ssh.

Is there any tools to detect what service use this port ? Any other request than these two I can test ? I am wondering what it is used for and if there is any risks with it.

Comment: what is the make and model of the camera?

Comment: DLink DCS2130 http://ur1.ca/9gphw

Answer (score 7):

You can try nmap with nmap -sV, who is much more intrusive when searching for services.

Comment: Thanks, but I got no more information, just "1010/tcp  open  surf?". There was a "1 service unrecognized" warning but concerning another port (running rtsp). Any other idea ?

Comment: Even with the parameter --version-all to check every service it found nothing. Should I start suspecting something odd ?

Comment: It could be some proprietary service or functionality built specifically for that camera. Have you tried checking the documentation?

Comment: There is a few services available that could maybe use that : pppoe, dynamic dns, upnp, ntp clock. The list of application I found in the source code (open source because of gpl regulation) of the firmware http://paste.mart-e.be/raw/jokihoqowi

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but hopefully a recipe to get one.  Teach a man how to fish:

The [manual for this camera is available here](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/business-solutions/ip-surveillance/business-ip-cameras/cube-cameras/-/media/Business_Products/DCS/DCS%202130/Manual/DCS_2130_A1_Manual_v100_EN_UK.pdf)

This camera provides a lot of functionality, both administrative (restricing IPs and users) and functional (snapshots, moving the camera, panning, zooming, audio recording, motion detection).

One way to figure out which of the many services listens specifically on port 1010 would be to use this 2 step process:

- Run a sniffer on the network (e.g. wireshark, or tcpdump) on a separate computer and display anything with a destination port 1010 and target IP of the camera device
- Try various actions in the camera control software (which runs only on windows) and see which of those actions specifically, lead to traffic to that IP/port.